# Using Cypher within the Clojure Neocons library. Where's the synergy?

Tags: clojure, neo4j, cypher

Being new to both clojure and neo4j I'm sure that I'm missing the point of the Neocons library, but I can't find a sensible way of mixing the library's "native" functions like node/update with results returned from cypher/tquery.

Creating a node in neo4j via node/create returns:

```
clojurewerkz.neocons.rest.records.Node{:id 999,
:location-uri        http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/999,
:data {:url http://clojureneo4j.info :color "blue"},
:relationships-uri nil,
:create-relationship-uri http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/999/relationships}
```

node/find "Finds nodes using the index". But in this case I didn't set one up and it's possible that I don't know the node's ID in the future. So I resort to Cypher to find the node by some other property (in this case its id for sake of argument):

```
(clojurewerkz.neocons.rest.cypher/tquery conn "MATCH (n) WHERE id(n) = 999 RETURN n")
```

Which returns

```
({"n"
{:properties "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/999/properties",
:create_relationship
"http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/999/relationships",
:labels "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/999/labels",
:incoming_relationships
"http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/999/relationships/in",
:outgoing_relationships
"http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/999/relationships/out",
:property "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/999/properties/{key}",
:paged_traverse
"http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/999/paged/traverse/{returnType}{?pageSize,leaseTime}",
:incoming_typed_relationships
"http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/999/relationships/in/{-list|&|types}",
:traverse
"http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/999/traverse/{returnType}",
:all_relationships
"http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/999/relationships/all",
:extensions {},
:outgoing_typed_relationships
"http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/999/relationships/out/{-list|&|types}",
:metadata {:id 999, :labels []},
:all_typed_relationships
"http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/999/relationships/all/{-list|&|types}",
:self "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/999",
:data {:domain "clojureneo4j.info" :color "blue"}}})
```

Now, if I want to update the "color" attribute of this found node then I have to destructure the result to get its id from :metadata, and I have to resupply all of the old attributes from :metadata in order for them to be retained along with the new associated color value. Something like:

```
(node/update conn (:id (:metadata node)) (assoc (:data node) :color "green"))
```

(That might not be exactly correct but I'm not sitting at a repl. Hopefully it gets the point across.)

Am I missing something obvious? How am I supposed to easily retrieve and update nodes when mixing in Cypher queries, or when I don't have an index or the node's ID filed away? Shouldn't I be able to associate a new value to a Cypher query result and hand it back to node/update?

Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't you just specify the attributes you want to change?
Otherwise you'll send all data (changed and unchanged) back to the db...

So just `(node/update conn (:id (:metadata node)) {:color "green"})` ?